# Setting up Dataprovider

Tags: apache-flex

I have a php service like this.

```
    <stockproductservice:StockproductService id="stockproductService"
                                             fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                                             showBusyCursor="true"/>
```

and it use a php serivce.

how should I set up the dataprovider in the itemRedenerer?

```
        <s:DataService source="{stockproductService.getAllStockproduct1()}"/>
```

and

```
        <s:WebService source="{stockproductService.getAllStockproduct1()}"/>
```

are not working.

Comment: An itemRenderer has no dataProvider. It's often part of a ListBased component that has the dataProvider, say a List with an ArrayCollection as dataprovider. The ItemRenderer is the component that renders the items in the list and has the prop: public function set data(value:Object) {...} that receives an object from the ArrayCollection. The DataService is the part that's responsible for fetching the data from the server and for example creating the ArrayCollection. You should state your question differently.

Comment: So, how to set up the dataProvider using the php service? Appearly, the result form the php service is not a array collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how to set up a WebService to populate a dataProvider in the simplest form it could be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <s:List dataProvider="{restaurants}" labelField="name" />

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:WebService id="RestaurantWS" wsdl="http://examples.adobe.com/flex3app/restaurant_ws/RestaurantWS.xml?wsdl" /> 
        <s:CallResponder id="getRestaurantsResult" 
                         result="restaurants = getRestaurantsResult.lastResult as ArrayCollection"/> 
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            public var restaurants:ArrayCollection;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                getRestaurantsResult.token = RestaurantWS.getRestaurants(); 
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: I had figure how to create the item redenerer. Just use Data.XXXX like this   <s:Label text="Stock ID {data.idstockProduct}" />
  <s:Label text="Product# {data.ProductDetail_idProduct}"/>       can populate the result of the php service. Anyway, thank for the example